# Application_Start and Application_BeginRequest will be called on my DevMachine (IIS Express) but not on the productive machine (IIS 8)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have developed a dataservice. In Global.asax.cs I have

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication {
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Global));
    protected void Application_Start() {
       log.Debug("Starting ...");
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       log.Debug("Application_BeginRequest ...");
       Proconact.DataService.CorsSupport.HandlePreflightRequest(HttpContext.Current);
    }
}
```

When I call

```
http://proconact.symas-design.ch:8082/proconactmobiledemo/DataService.svc/Authenticate?username=%27demo%27&password=%27demo123%27
```

my method in the dataservice will be called:

```
[WebGet]
public bool Authenticate(string username, string password) {
    log.DebugFormat("Authenticate '{0}' / '{1}'", username, password);
    return true;
}
```

and the log is written the my log-file.

But the strange is, that the log-entries from `Application_Start()` and `Application_BeginRequest()` are never written - so I think, they are never called.

In `Application_BeginRequest()` I have implemented support for CORS - but it is not working. Because of this I have looked into this and added the logs.

Does I something missing? Am I wrong for expecting, that `Application_BeginRequest()` should be called when I execute the statement above?

Comment: Have you tried killing the app-pool process on IIS and then trying again?

Comment: Yes, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Is IIS 8 configured correctly for the application? Is it configured to run the requests to the site as an application? How is the project deployed to the server?